# How can I add a css file from web-app/css directory in grails

Tags: grails

I use `<link type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'calender.css')}" />`

i don't know why this tag not working.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? url going nowhere (404)?  not generated? broken html? ...

Comment: no effect of css in my GSP page.

Comment: then you should check, what is actually in your generated html and add all this informations to your question.  "does not work" is a surefire way to get downvoted on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to go back to my recent projects because this is something you set up once and never need to change again. I usually use this line at the top of my gsp files:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<g:createLinkTo dir='css' file='style.css'/>" />
```

But for this to work just double check that you have the `CSS` directory inside `web-app`:

```
<YourProject>      
  |--> web-app
        |--> css
        |--> images
        |--> js
        |--> META-INF
        |--> WEB-INF
```

That is normally the directory structure that Grails expects when you tell it to build your WAR file.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this it will solve your problem:-

```
<g:resource dir="css" file="calender.css" />
```

For further information go to grails documentation: [click here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you're supposed to include CSS files in a page when using the resources plugin. You're supposed to define resource bundles/modules in a file `grails-app/conf/AppResources.groovy`. Then you use the `r:require` tag to include whole modules in your page. See the [resource plugin docs](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) for more details.